# jQuery validation plugin: can't call default submit within submitHandler

Tags: jquery, validation, submit

I'm trying to setup a form using [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), which on submit first makes an ajax request and then submits using the default submit method.  Everything works fine, except that I can't trigger the default submission. My (simplified) submitHandler:

```
submitHandler: function(form, event){
    var successful; 
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
        error: function(){
            successful = false;
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        if (response){
            successful = true;
        } else {
            successful = false;
        };
    });
    if (successful){
        $(form).submit();
    };
}
```

The `$(form).submit()` causes a "submit-loop" but does not trigger the default submit; Replacing it with `form.submit()` does nothing.

Have I missed anything in how to properly trigger the default submit event?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the triggering of the ajax check from the $(form).submit(). Put a "Submit" button on the form and perform the ajax check in an onclick handler. If all is OK then call the $(form).submit() without any fear of a loop.

```
  <form id="myform"...>
       ....
       <button type="button" id="submitbtn">Submit<button>
  </form>
```

the javascript...

```
  $("#submitbtn").click(function() { 
     // put your ajax call in here
     //then 
    if (successful){
        $("#myform").submit();
    };
  }}
```

Comment: Would the onClick event be triggered before or after form validation?

Comment: The onclick is triggered by the user clicking the button to submit the form. But it is not a type="Submit" button linked to the form - it's independent of the form. In fact you can position it outside the form. if you want to. All the button click does is trigger a call to your onclick handler, which can then choose whether to submit the form or not, based on the ajax. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does. The thing is that I want the ajax request to be made after form validation but before the actual submission. Hence I'm using the ```$("form").validate()``` method from the jquery-validation plugin with a ```submitHandler```

Comment: I thought the ajax was doing the validation?

Comment: according to the docs, you should use  form.submit();, not $(form).submit(); because of this recursion problem. https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ ... "form.submit() ... triggers the native submit event ... and not the validation"

Comment: Maybe you can get direct help... https://jqueryvalidation.org/   says  Please post questions to the official using jQuery Plugins Forum, tagging your question with (at least) "validate".